# Efficient way of paging through records in DB2 table

Tags: sql, db2

I am using below query to page through records in DB2 table

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY sequence_no
            ) AS rn
        ,table_name.*
    FROM table_name
    )
WHERE rn BETWEEN 1
        AND 1000
```

This query runs very slow when records in table are more than 2,3 million then query performs really sluggishly. It is taking more than 40-50 seconds to put out thousand records.

What other way is there to make this run faster?

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?  That will make a difference...

Comment: I doubt there's a magic trick to sort a 2 million row table, unless you have a clustered index on `sequence_no`

Comment: If you have any sequence no, then its very easy. You write fetch first 1000 rows only. and in the where clause use where SEQNO > variable. Your var should start with 0. Then on each page you pass the max seq not fetched last time. So next time its like where seqno > 1000 fetch first 1000 rows only and so no